# why some images are underlined with red in android studio and others not?

Tags: image, android-studio, gimp

In Android Studio I imported pictures using `File | New | image asset`. Some pictures work fine but others are not only underlined with a zigzag red line in the project structure area but also I can't use them in my project. The images underlined with red are in the drawable folder.
For example I imported a picture "pizza-small.jpg" and it didn't work. I tried to change the format using Gimp to a png picture but without success. I tried changing the resolution and aspect ration without success also.

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox.
I googled the question many times without success.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can AS use that image? Did you try to rename it without a dash? Is there a spell checker active? Can you post a link to that unaltered PNG?

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I renamed it with a dash and and the error was gone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by renaming the file name of the picture from "pizza-small.png" to "pizza_small.png".